# How to monitor execution of new root process?

Tags: unix, operating-system, monitoring

I want to exec a script when a new root process starts (on Linux).
How can I simply do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will be tricky, as the script would probably also be *spawned* as root -- and then even every external command in it.

But I think it is possible with [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/).

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17334029/585725) explains how to get notified about creation of new processes and will tell you process IDs.

Given the process ID you can trivially determine whether the process belongs to UID 0, i.e. user `root`.