# Forcefully remove fcntl locks from a different process

Tags: c, linux, locking, fcntl

Is there any way I can remove fcntl byte range locks on a file from a process that *did not* lock these ranges?

I have several processes that put byte range locks on files. What I basically need to come up with is an *external* tool that would help me remove byte range locks for files I specify.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options that immediately come to mind.

1. Write a kernel module to do this.
   As far as I know, there is no kernel facility to do this as of right now.
   (You could add a new command to `fcntl()`, that given superuser privileges or same user as the owner of the lock, does the force-unlock or lock stealing.)
2. Write a small library, that installs a realtime signal handler, say `SIGRTMAX`. When this signal is caught, sent by `sigqueue()`, and the `int` payload describes an open file descriptor, release all byte locks on that descriptor.

   Alternatively, you can have the signal handler open and read a file or pipe (say `/tmp/PID.lock`, where the file or pipe contains a data packet defining which file or file descriptor and byte range to unlock.

   As long as the library is loaded when the process starts (and possibly interposing all `signal()` and `sigaction()` calls to make sure your signal is kept in the call chain), this should work fine.

The second option requires that you preload the library (via `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable, or preloading it for all binaries using `/etc/ld.so.conf`).

The interposing library is not difficult at all to write. I have shown an example of using an interposing library to [monitor `fork()` calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256790/how-to-monitor-an-external-process-for-events-by-its-pid-in-c/17366235#17366235). In your case, you'd have to think of a good way to define the byte ranges to be unlocked (in file or pipe, triggered by a signal), and handle all that in the signal handler context; but there are enough async-signal-safe low-level `unistd.h` I/O functions to do this.