# How to continuously monitor process creation in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, process, monitoring, vala

My process launches a process - let it be a shell in this example, but it's applicable to any process really. I need to get notified when the shell creates new processes and to obtain their PIDs.

I can take a snapshot of the whole process tree at any given time (well, `pstree` can), but how do I monitor creation of new processes by a process with a given PID?

So far I've found several ways to do so at [How to monitor an external process for events by its PID in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256790/how-to-monitor-an-external-process-for-events-by-its-pid-in-c) none of which really solve my problem:

1. Monitoring NetLink proc interfaces. **Problem:** requires root permissions which I do not have.
2. Custom library overriding the syscalls loaded into the shell process by `LD_PRELOAD`. **Problem:** it will be inherited by the children of the shell as well, and I do not want that - I only want to monitor the shell.
3. `ptrace()`ing the shell. **Problem:** flags that notify the parent (i.e. my process) about creating new processes, i.e. `PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK`, `PTRACE_O_TRACEVFORK` and `PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE` propagate `ptrace()`ing to child processes, and I only want to monitor the shell.
4. Making the shell cooperate. **Problem:** In BASH command callbacks (as used in undistract-me) are very hacky. I'd also prefer to avoid shell-specific code.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here. I feel like I could make one of the above solutions work with *more* hacks, but... surely I don't have to resort to the big guns like `LD_PRELOAD` and `ptrace()` for such a simple task, do I?

JFYI I'm coding this in Vala, but C snippets are welcome too.

Comment: So for the record I had to make the shell cooperate. ZSH has pre-exec hook documented in http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html, KSH has a debug hook documented in http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ksh/, and a hack that adds pre-exec to BASH can be found in https://github.com/jml/undistract-me

Answer (score 4):

No generic solution has been found so far so I had to resort to making the shell cooperate:

- ZSH has pre-exec hook documented in
  http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html
- KSH has a
  debug hook documented in http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ksh/
- a hack that adds pre-exec to BASH can be found in
  https://github.com/jml/undistract-me

I simply write callback commands into the relevant environment variables depending on the shell.