# Explanation: fork system call interception

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fork, system-calls

I am not able to understand the working of the following code that basically intercept the fork system call

```
pid_t fork(void)
{
    pid_t result;
    if (!actual_fork) {
        const int saved_errno = errno;

        *(void **)&actual_fork = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "fork");
        if (!actual_fork) {
            errno = EAGAIN;
            return (pid_t)-1;
        }

        errno = saved_errno;
    }

    result = (*actual_fork)();
    if (!result && commfd != -1) {
        struct message msg;
        notify(TYPE_FORK, &msg, sizeof msg);
    }

    printf("\n%d",result);
    fflush(stdout);
    return result;
}
```

when exporting the following intercepted code with LD_PRELOAD, then any process that calls for nested fork throws **Segmentation fault**

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking - are you referring to the `Segmentation fault` or how the hijack is done?

Comment: Is `actual_fork` correctly initialized?

Comment: Why can `actual_fork` not be assigned without the cast ? It seems like now it would have to be a pointer to a NULL pointer, so the guard would not be `!actual_fork`, but `!*actual_fork`

Comment: I think the main problem is that `&actual_fork` in your `dlsym` line should be `(&actual_fork)`

Comment: @IshayPeled i am not able to understand the working of the code ... which implies the reason  for seg fault.

Comment: How is actual_fork defined? You should just use: `pid_t (*actual_fork)(); actual_fork = dlsym(...); actual_fork();`

Comment: Is your code the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/17366235/2554472 or did you change anything?

Comment: The code entirely is not the same ... I have used its fork method only

Comment: @ctx both the definitions are same ..